# How to nest LogEntries in GCP Stackdriver logging UI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Using the GCP Logging Client or API terminology, how does one nest log entries as shown in this image?

[image: nested logs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use-case is explained in the [AppEngline Logs docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs#linking_application_logs_and_requests).

Make sure to also set the `traceId` fields to non-null values on the request and app logs which you are sending. Here's sample code in Scala:

```
import com.google.cloud.MonitoredResource
import com.google.cloud.logging.Payload._
import com.google.cloud.logging._
import collection.JavaConverters._
import org.threeten.bp.Duration

val logging = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
val traceId = "keasdfwxcbrbntpoiuwehrtiojsadf";

var firstEntry = {
  LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of("string-payload-one"))
    .setSeverity(Severity.ERROR)
    .setLogName("app")
    .setTimestamp(1519955138399L)
    .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
    .setLabels(Map("environment" -> "testing").asJava)
    .setTrace(traceId)
    .build()
}

var midEntry = {
  LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of("string-payload-two"))
    .setSeverity(Severity.INFO)
    .setLogName("request")
    .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
    .setHttpRequest(HttpRequest.newBuilder().setStatus(200).setRequestUrl("/about-us").setLatency(Duration.ofMillis(1234)).build())
    .setTimestamp(1519955137906L)
    .setLabels(Map("environment" -> "testing").asJava)
    .setTrace(traceId)
    .build()
}

var lastEntry = {
  LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of("string-payload-three"))
    .setSeverity(Severity.ERROR)
    .setLogName("app")
    .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
    .setTimestamp(1519955138523L)
    .setLabels(Map("environment" -> "testing").asJava)
    .setTrace(traceId)
    .build()
}

logging.write(List(firstEntry, midEntry, lastEntry).asJava)
```

At the end, the log entries should show up both in their individual logs and "cross-logged" as children of their requests, like this:

[image]